# Same htaccess URL points to two different locations

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

With news.domain.com I'd like to have it redirect to www.domain.com/news which displays all the posts. I've got this working.

However when a user visits and old Tumblr to WordPress link like so:

news.domain.com/post/[ID]/[POST TITLE] I'd like to have it redirect to:

www.domain.com/[POST TITLE]

The problem I'm having is news.domain.com to www.domain.com/news is messing with the posts rewrite and pre-pending it to the URL like this: www.domain.com/news/[POST TITLE] which doesn't work.

How do I set up htaccess to work for both scenarios?

Comment: htaccess file is setup like so but this doesn't work for both scenarios:

#force if only news.domain.com to go to www.domain.com/news
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/news [L,R=301]

# Handle all old post redirect links correctly
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on



#Rule for /PostTitle
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://domain.com/$3 [R,NC,L]


#Rule  for /news
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/news [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey Starkeen, thanks for the response. I can get the post title working now, but the news.domain.com just redirects to www.domain.com and not www.domain.com/news. You think this might be related to having a CNAME setup for news.domain.com which simply points to the same place as www.domain.com?

Comment: Ok, chrome seems to be responding to news.domain.com and redirecting me to: www.domain.com/news with your code. It also maintains the post title redirect.

Other browsers seem to be defaulting to news.domain.com just pointing to www.domain.com.

I've reset caches and things, I'm not sure why the other browsers aren't following suite.

Comment: I'm also using R=301 instead of simply R. Is this going to be problematic for other browsers that aggressively cache the 301?